# ajax-jquery not working for Spring MVC on change event of select

Tags: ajax, jquery, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC. I want my jsp page to use ajax to populate a select box on the change event of another select box..

the jsp page is like..

```
    <c:url var="RatePlanOfClientURL" value="/ratePlansofUser.jav" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
      <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
              $("#parentClient").change(function(){
                  $.getJSON('${RatePlanOfClientURL}', {
                      clientId : $(this).val(),
                        ajax : 'true'
                    },
                    function(data) {
                                alert("hai");
                        var html = '<option value="">Select '+$("#parentClient").val()+'</option>';
                        var len = data.length;
                        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            html += '<option value="' + data[i].rateID + '">' + data[i].rateName
                                    + '</option>';
                        }
                        html += '</option>';


                    $('#ratePlanList').html(html);
                });
            });
        });

    </script>


<fieldset>
<div>
 <label> Parent Account</label>
                       <form:select id="parentClient" path="reseller.clientResellerParentId" class="addDropdown">
                                 <form:option value="0" label="Select Parent"></form:option> 
                                <form:options items="${ClientList}" itemValue="clientId" itemLabel="clientName"/>
                            </form:select>
</div>

<div>
<label >Rate Plan</label>
                           <form:select id="ratePlanList" path="reseller.resellerRateplan.ratePlanID" class="addDropdown">
                                <form:option value="0" label="Select RatePlan"></form:option> 
                                <form:options items="${RatePlanList}" itemValue="rateID" itemLabel="rateName"/>
                            </form:select>
                            <form:errors path="reseller.resellerRateplan.ratePlanID" cssStyle="color:red"></form:errors>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

And in my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ratePlansofUser.jav", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<RatePlanData> ratePlansForClient(
            @RequestParam(value = "clientId", required = true) Integer clientId,
            HttpSession session) 
    {
        System.out.println("Reached Controller for "+clientId);
        return ratePlanService.getRatePlanForClient(clientId);
    }
```

Atlast the database controller class i have

```
 public List<RatePlanData> getRatePlanForClient(int id)
     {
        Criteria myCriteria = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(RatePlanData.class);

        myCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("clientID",id ));  

        return myCriteria.list();
     }
```

Whenever i change my parentclient select box, the controller method is calling( the `System.out.println("Reached Controller for "+clientId);` is printing). And when i select a parent which doesnt have any child, the alert box in that script is displaying. But when i call a parent which has child, it is not working(that alert box is not displaying, but that `System.out.println("Reached Controller for "+clientId);` is printing at console).

Can anyone point out what may the problem?

Thanks in advance..

Edit..
I had checked the variable data in the ajax function in script with firebug. it shows the value for data as '[ ]' when i am selecting a parent which has no child. And it just skips all the scripts when it encounters the function(data). Does anyone got any idea??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure that your service call doesn't throw any exception. Secondly if there is no exception, you might be missing the Id / element name generated by spring tag (assuming you are using spring tag lib)

Comment: Sorry, im new to this.. Can u just make the answer little bit brief. And can u suggest how i could do those checkings?